# Programmatically convert pandas dataframe to markdown table

Tags: python, pandas, markdown

I have a Pandas Dataframe generated from a database, which has data with mixed encodings. For example:

```
+----+-------------------------+----------+------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| ID | path                    | language | date       | longest_sentence                               | shortest_sentence                                      | number_words | readability_consensus |
+----+-------------------------+----------+------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| 0  | data/Eng/Sagitarius.txt | Eng      | 2015-09-17 | With administrative experience in the prepa... | I am able to relocate internationally on short not...  | 306          | 11th and 12th grade   |
+----+-------------------------+----------+------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| 31 | data/Nor/Høylandet.txt  | Nor      | 2015-07-22 | Høgskolen i Østfold er et eksempel...          | Som skuespiller har jeg både...                        | 253          | 15th and 16th grade   |
+----+-------------------------+----------+------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
```

As seen there is a mix of English and Norwegian (encoded as ISO-8859-1 in the database I think). I need to get the contents of this Dataframe output as a Markdown table, but without getting problems with encoding. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15445930/603387) (from the question [Generate Markdown tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394140/generate-markdown-tables)) and got the following:

```
import sys, sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect("Applications.db")
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT path, language, date, longest_sentence, shortest_sentence, number_words, readability_consensus FROM applications ORDER BY date(date) DESC", db)
db.close()

rows = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    items = (row['date'], 
             row['path'], 
             row['language'], 
             row['shortest_sentence'],
             row['longest_sentence'], 
             row['number_words'], 
             row['readability_consensus'])
    rows.append(items)

headings = ['Date', 
            'Path', 
            'Language',
            'Shortest Sentence', 
            'Longest Sentence since', 
            'Words',
            'Grade level']

fields = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
align = [('^', '<'), ('^', '^'), ('^', '<'), ('^', '^'), ('^', '>'),
         ('^','^'), ('^','^')]

table(sys.stdout, rows, fields, headings, align)
```

However, this yields an `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe5' in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)` error. How can I output the Dataframe as a Markdown table? That is, for the purpose of storing this code in a file for use in writing a Markdown document. I need the output to look like this:

```
| ID | path                    | language | date       | longest_sentence                               | shortest_sentence                                      | number_words | readability_consensus |
|----|-------------------------|----------|------------|------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------------|--------------|-----------------------|
| 0  | data/Eng/Sagitarius.txt | Eng      | 2015-09-17 | With administrative experience in the prepa... | I am able to relocate internationally on short not...  | 306          | 11th and 12th grade   |
| 31 | data/Nor/Høylandet.txt  | Nor      | 2015-07-22 | Høgskolen i Østfold er et eksempel...          | Som skuespiller har jeg både...                        | 253          | 15th and 16th grade   |
```

Comment: Try this: `new_string = string.decode('latin1')`, where string = "Høgskolen i Østfold er et eksempel..." In other words use `decode('latin1')` on your string to decode Norwegian characters.

Comment: I set up a switch structure for decoding when ``language == 'Nor'``: 
enc = 'latin1'
items = (row['date'].decode(enc), row['path'].decode(enc), row['language'].decode(enc), row['shortest_sentence'].decode(enc), row['longest_sentence'].decode(enc) ...

But still get: ``UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe5' in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)``, specifically on ``row['longest_sentence'].decode(enc)``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so I've taken a leaf from a question suggested by [Rohit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625098/rohit) ([Python - Encoding string - Swedish Letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315629/python-encoding-string-swedish-letters)), extended [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33187706/603387), and came up with the following:

```
# Enforce UTF-8 encoding
import sys
stdin, stdout = sys.stdin, sys.stdout
reload(sys)
sys.stdin, sys.stdout = stdin, stdout
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF-8')

# SQLite3 database
import sqlite3
# Pandas: Data structures and data analysis tools
import pandas as pd

# Read database, attach as Pandas dataframe
db = sqlite3.connect("Applications.db")
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT path, language, date, shortest_sentence, longest_sentence, number_words, readability_consensus FROM applications ORDER BY date(date) DESC", db)
db.close()
df.columns = ['Path', 'Language', 'Date', 'Shortest Sentence', 'Longest Sentence', 'Words', 'Readability Consensus']

# Parse Dataframe and apply Markdown, then save as 'table.md'
cols = df.columns
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['---','---','---','---','---','---','---']], columns=cols)
df3 = pd.concat([df2, df])
df3.to_csv("table.md", sep="|", index=False)
```

An important precursor to this is that the `shortest_sentence` and `longest_sentence` columns do not contain unnecessary line breaks, as removed by applying `.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')` to them before submitting into the SQLite database. It appears that the solution is not to enforce the language-specific encoding (`ISO-8859-1` for Norwegian), but rather that `UTF-8` is used instead of the default `ASCII`.

I ran this through my IPython notebook (Python 2.7.10) and got a table like the following (fixed spacing for appearance here):

```
| Path                    | Language | Date       | Shortest Sentence                                                                            | Longest Sentence                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         | Words | Readability Consensus |
|-------------------------|----------|------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-------|-----------------------|
| data/Eng/Something1.txt | Eng      | 2015-09-17 | I am able to relocate to London on short notice.                                             | With my administrative experience in the preparation of the structure and content of seminars in various courses, and critiquing academic papers on various levels, I am confident that I can execute the work required as an editorial assistant.       | 306   | 11th and 12th grade   |
| data/Nor/NoeNorrønt.txt | Nor      | 2015-09-17 | Jeg har grundig kjennskap til Microsoft Office og Adobe.                                     | I løpet av studiene har jeg vært salgsmedarbeider for et større konsern, hvor jeg solgte forsikring til studentene og de faglige ansatte ved universitetet i Trønderlag, samt renholdsarbeider i et annet, hvor jeg i en periode var avdelingsansvarlig. | 205   | 18th and 19th grade   |
| data/Nor/Ørret.txt.txt  | Nor      | 2015-09-17 | Jeg håper på positiv tilbakemelding, og møter naturligvis til intervju hvis det er ønskelig. | I løpet av studiene har jeg vært salgsmedarbeider for et større konsern, hvor jeg solgte forsikring til studentene og de faglige ansatte ved universitetet i Trønderlag, samt renholdsarbeider i et annet, hvor jeg i en periode var avdelingsansvarlig. | 160   | 18th and 19th grade   |
```

Thus, a Markdown table without problems with encoding.

Comment: Calling `sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF-8')` is an ultra bad idea. It masks all kind of issues and it looks like your new code doesn't need it as you're not calling `table()`, which is full of implied encodings.

Answer (score 47):

Pandas 1.0 was released 29 january 2020 and supports markdown conversion, so you can now do this directly!

Example taken from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#converting-to-markdown):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [1, 2, 3]}, index=['a', 'a', 'b'])
print(df.to_markdown())
```

```
|    |   A |   B |
|:---|----:|----:|
| a  |   1 |   1 |
| a  |   2 |   2 |
| b  |   3 |   3 |
```

Or without the index:

```py
print(df.to_markdown(index=False)) # use 'showindex' for pandas < 1.1
```

```
|   A |   B |
|----:|----:|
|   1 |   1 |
|   2 |   2 |
|   3 |   3 |
```

Comment: Any way to remove the index when converting to markdown? Passing `index=False` didn't work.

Comment: Yes: `df.to_markdown(showindex=False)`. Pandas uses [tabulate](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate), so you can pass tabulate parameters via to_markdown().

Comment: FutureWarning: `showindex` is deprecated. Only 'index' will be used in a future version.

Comment: Thanks, indeed futurewarning shows up with `pandas>=1.1`. Updated answer.

Answer (score 40):

Improving the answer further, for use in IPython Notebook:

```
def pandas_df_to_markdown_table(df):
    from IPython.display import Markdown, display
    fmt = ['---' for i in range(len(df.columns))]
    df_fmt = pd.DataFrame([fmt], columns=df.columns)
    df_formatted = pd.concat([df_fmt, df])
    display(Markdown(df_formatted.to_csv(sep="|", index=False)))

pandas_df_to_markdown_table(infodf)
```

Or use [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate):

```
pip install tabulate
```

Examples of use are in the documentation.

**Update**

As of pandas 1.0 DataFrame to markdown is available. Please see answer from @timvink ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html))

Comment: To use tabulate, I used `print(tabulate.tabulate(df.values,df.columns, tablefmt="pipe"))`

Comment: I changed last line of function from `to_csv` to `to_clipboard` so that I could paste the results easily.

Comment: `df.to_markdown()` is available now on Pandas which is using `tabulate`.

Answer (score 40):

I recommend [python-tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) library for generating ascii-tables. The library supports `pandas.DataFrame` as well.

Here is how to use it:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
from tabulate import tabulate

df = DataFrame({
    "weekday": ["monday", "thursday", "wednesday"],
    "temperature": [20, 30, 25],
    "precipitation": [100, 200, 150],
}).set_index("weekday")

print(tabulate(df, tablefmt="pipe", headers="keys"))
```

Output:

```
| weekday   |   temperature |   precipitation |
|:----------|--------------:|----------------:|
| monday    |            20 |             100 |
| thursday  |            30 |             200 |
| wednesday |            25 |             150 |
```

Comment: You can do this with `tablefmt="pipe"`. That PR was declined and there is no `tablefmt="markdown"`.

Answer (score 11):

Try this out. I got it to work.

See the screenshot of my markdown file converted to HTML at the end of this answer.

```
import pandas as pd

# You don't need these two lines
# as you already have your DataFrame in memory
df = pd.read_csv("nor.txt", sep="|")
df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1)

# Get column names
cols = df.columns

# Create a new DataFrame with just the markdown
# strings
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['---',]*len(cols)], columns=cols)

#Create a new concatenated DataFrame
df3 = pd.concat([df2, df])

#Save as markdown
df3.to_csv("nor.md", sep="|", index=False)
```

[image: My output in HTML format by converting HTML to Markdown]

Comment: Relative to my dataframe there were a couple extra separators, but running this:
``cols = df.columns
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['---','---','---','---','---','---','---']], columns=cols)
df3 = pd.concat([df2, df])
df3.to_csv("nor.md", sep="|", index=False)``

Still gives a encoding error: ``UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe5' in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)``. Also, out of curiosity, would it be problematic that ``shortest_sentence`` and ``longest_sentence`` may contain line breaks?

Comment: I do not think the line breaks should matter as long as they show up fine in pandas DataFrame. Pandas should be able to take in unicode characters just fine so I am not sure why this does not work. Check out this question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315629/python-encoding-string-swedish-letters). I do not know how close Swedish is to Norwegian but you may find something helpful.

Comment: If you find an answer to your problem, do answer your own question for posterity.

Comment: Through some further testing I was able to, and using the elegant solution you proposed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

## Export a DataFrame to markdown

I created the following function for exporting a pandas.DataFrame to markdown in Python:

```python
def df_to_markdown(df, float_format='%.2g'):
    """
    Export a pandas.DataFrame to markdown-formatted text.
    DataFrame should not contain any `|` characters.
    """
    from os import linesep
    return linesep.join([
        '|'.join(df.columns),
        '|'.join(4 * '-' for i in df.columns),
        df.to_csv(sep='|', index=False, header=False, float_format=float_format)
    ]).replace('|', ' | ')
```

This function may not automatically fix the encoding issues of the OP, but that is a different issue than converting from pandas to markdown.

Comment: I needed to modify this function to add `|` to the beginning and end of each line in the DataFrame to get proper markdown output.

Comment: Useful when usecase is to copy-paste a dataframe in markdown format.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried several of the above solutions in this post and found this worked most consistently.

To convert a pandas data frame to a markdown table I suggest using [pytablewriter](http://pytablewriter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
Using the data provided in this post:

```
import pandas as pd
import pytablewriter
from StringIO import StringIO

c = StringIO("""ID, path,language, date,longest_sentence, shortest_sentence, number_words , readability_consensus 
0, data/Eng/Sagitarius.txt , Eng, 2015-09-17 , With administrative experience in the prepa... , I am able to relocate internationally on short not..., 306, 11th and 12th grade
31 , data/Nor/Høylandet.txt  , Nor, 2015-07-22 , Høgskolen i Østfold er et eksempel..., Som skuespiller har jeg både..., 253, 15th and 16th grade
""")
df = pd.read_csv(c,sep=',',index_col=['ID'])

writer = pytablewriter.MarkdownTableWriter()
writer.table_name = "example_table"
writer.header_list = list(df.columns.values)
writer.value_matrix = df.values.tolist()
writer.write_table()
```

This results in:

```
# example_table
ID |           path           |language|    date    |                longest_sentence                |                   shortest_sentence                  | number_words | readability_consensus 
--:|--------------------------|--------|------------|------------------------------------------------|------------------------------------------------------|-------------:|-----------------------
  0| data/Eng/Sagitarius.txt  | Eng    | 2015-09-17 | With administrative experience in the prepa... | I am able to relocate internationally on short not...|           306| 11th and 12th grade   
 31| data/Nor/Høylandet.txt  | Nor    | 2015-07-22 | Høgskolen i Østfold er et eksempel...        | Som skuespiller har jeg både...                      |           253| 15th and 16th grade
```

Here is a markdown rendered screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Excellent, elegantly render in both editor and preview !

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for how to do this using `tabulate`, I thought I'd put this here to save you some time:

`print(tabulate(df, tablefmt="pipe", headers="keys", showindex=False))`

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution. This time via thin wrapper around tabulate: [tabulatehelper](https://github.com/kiwi0fruit/tabulatehelper)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tabulatehelper as th

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(16).reshape(4, 4), columns=('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
print(th.md_table(df, formats={-1: 'c'}))
```

Output:

```
|        a |        b |        c |        d |
|---------:|---------:|---------:|:--------:|
| 0.413284 | 0.932373 | 0.277797 | 0.646333 |
| 0.552731 | 0.381826 | 0.141727 | 0.2483   |
| 0.779889 | 0.012458 | 0.308352 | 0.650859 |
| 0.301109 | 0.982111 | 0.994024 | 0.43551  |
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas have merged a PR to support df.**to_markdown()**  method. You can find more details [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/30350) It should be available soon.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example function using `pytablewriter` and some regular expressions to make the markdown table more similar to how a dataframe looks on Jupyter (with the row headers bold).

```
import io
import re
import pandas as pd
import pytablewriter

def df_to_markdown(df):
    """
    Converts Pandas DataFrame to markdown table,
    making the index bold (as in Jupyter) unless it's a
    pd.RangeIndex, in which case the index is completely dropped.
    Returns a string containing markdown table.
    """
    isRangeIndex = isinstance(df.index, pd.RangeIndex)
    if not isRangeIndex:
        df = df.reset_index()
    writer = pytablewriter.MarkdownTableWriter()
    writer.stream = io.StringIO()
    writer.header_list = df.columns
    writer.value_matrix = df.values
    writer.write_table()
    writer.stream.seek(0)
    table = writer.stream.readlines()

    if isRangeIndex:
        return ''.join(table)
    else:
        # Make the indexes bold
        new_table = table[:2]
        for line in table[2:]:
            new_table.append(re.sub('^(.*?)\|', r'**\1**|', line))    

        return ''.join(new_table)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using external tool `pandoc` and pipe:

```
def to_markdown(df):
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    s = df.to_latex()
    p = Popen('pandoc -f latex -t markdown',
              stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
    stdoutdata, _ = p.communicate(input=s.encode("utf-8"))
    return stdoutdata.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Opening another process seems vulnerable to unforeseen problems but for the simple case this is great.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3 returns Unicodes by default for TEXT fields. Everything was set up to work before you introduced the `table()` function from an external source (that you did not provide in your question).

The `table()` function has `str()` calls which do not provide an encoding, so ASCII is used to protect you.

You need to re-write `table()` not to do this, especially as you've got Unicode objects. You may have some success by simply replacing `str()` with `unicode()`