# How to send a Dataframe with Telegram Bot in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, parsing, telegram, telegram-bot

So I'm working with a Telegram Bot which get data from SQL query and send the results to people.

I have tried to manual format the data return by the query but its not at my expectation. I also tried to use the Markdown and HTML parse mode of Telegram but did not success.

So I now I want to transform the query's results into a Dataframe (I have already did this), then how I can send the dataframe to telegram bot in python?

If sending a dataframe is not possible, then is there any better ways to do this?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I also used the telegram bot in python and also had some issues at the beginning. Can you share some code and data to better understand what your goal is? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to either to either generate an [ASCII table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181846/programmatically-convert-pandas-dataframe-to-markdown-table), or an [image of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634238/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-table-as-a-png) from your dataframe. [In my experience](https://gitlab.com/zavan/monetus-fia-bot), generating an image was the only way to always get a well formatted table on all clients.